# Xdebug with docker works fine except when i run test with PHPUnit

Tags: php, docker, debugging, phpunit, xdebug

I've this API running on docker, with this Xdebug configuration:

[image: image 1.1]

Everything works fine, except debugging test using play button in PhpStorm, when I try to debug the test this is the result:

[image: image 1.2]

Or this if I click the debug button instead of play button:

[image: image 1.3]

PHPUnit and server configuration in PhpStorm settings works fine and I think that this configuration are correct.

There is someone who can help me with this?

I've tried adding `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` tag into my php.ini, but probably it was added with wrong value.

Comment: `xdebug.remote_host` does not exist in Xdebug 3, so I don't know why PhpStorm uses that in its warning. Perhaps you're running a too-old version of PhpStorm?

Comment: No, i'm using the 2023.1 version

Comment: Please fix your xdebug config according to the xdebug 3 docs, and try again. At least `remote_host` should be replaced with `client_host`

Comment: But it's already with client_host. Like in the first picture

Comment: Could be that the PHP Interpreter info in PhpStorm is too old / does not show Xdebug v3. Otherwise I see no reason why it should mention v2 params...

Comment: *"except debugging test using play button in PhpStorm"* The Play button is for running the tests (or whatever the current Run/Debug Configuration type is) -- it is NOT for debugging. To debug you need to use the Debug button (surprise...) But yes, it's possible to debug with Run/Play button .. but why making things complicated (as it requires extra set up)

Comment: *"I've tried adding PHP_IDE_CONFIG tag into my php.ini"* 1) But the message in red where that PHP_IDE_CONFIG is mentioned clearly states **environment variable** and not php.ini. 2) And what exactly have you tried to use? What value did you use? It has to point to you `Settings | PHP | Servers` entry...

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully configured this setup in my VSCode environment, although I'm unsure about the process in PHPStorm. For some reason, in my case, PHPUnit didn't update the inline ini config as expected. To work around this issue, I executed the following command, encapsulating the PHPUnit executable within a PHP runtime:

```bash
docker exec -u akhatri -it eb1986e30bcc /bin/bash -c "cd $(pwd); php -d xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal -d xdebug.mode=debug -d xdebug.start_with_request=yes ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/UserPermissionTest.php"
```

This approach successfully worked for me with the following versions:

- VSCode: 1.84.2
- PHPUnit: 10.3.4
- xDebug: 3
- PHP: 8.2
- Docker container running Ubuntu Focal (20.04)